# How to change row color in datagridview online after change cell value C#?

Tags: c#

How can I change the row color in datagridview when type the cell value , I used the following code and cellFormatting event but its give error input string was not in a correct format when enter the value between lower limit and upper limit

```
private void dgvResult_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {

            if (dgvResult.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Result"].Value == DBNull.Value)
            {
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue;
            }

            else if (Convert.ToInt32(dgvResult.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Result"].Value.ToString()) >= Convert.ToInt32(dgvResult.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Lower Limit"].Value.ToString()) &&
            Convert.ToInt32(dgvResult.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Result"].Value.ToString()) <= Convert.ToInt32(dgvResult.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Upper Limit"].Value.ToString()))
            {
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue;
            }

            else if (Convert.ToInt32(dgvResult.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Result"].Value) < Convert.ToInt32(dgvResult.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Lower Limit"].Value) ||
                Convert.ToInt32(dgvResult.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Result"].Value) > Convert.ToInt32(dgvResult.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Upper Limit"].Value))
            {
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon;
            }
        }
```

Is this CellFormatting is the correct event or there is another event I can use to solve this issue  and change the row color after type the result value and compare it with lower and upper value ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is one of your values in not an int for some reason, try this code

```
private void dgvResult_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dgvResult.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Result"].Value == DBNull.Value)
    {
        e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue;
    }
    else
    {
        int cellValue = 0;
        int lowerLimit = 0;
        int upperLimit = 0;
        if (int.TryParse(dgvResult.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Result"].Value.ToString(), out cellValue) 
            && int.TryParse(dgvResult.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Lower Limit"].Value.ToString(), out lowerLimit)
            && int.TryParse(dgvResult.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Upper Limit"].Value.ToString(), out upperLimit)
            )
        {
            if(cellValue >= lowerLimit && cellValue <= upperLimit)
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue;
            else
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon;
        }
        else
        {
            // The cell value is not an int..
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon;
        }
    }
}
```

Put a break point on the line after "// The cell value is not an int.." and see what values are in the cells you are using.